# Android: add new view with a XML Layout file

Tags: android, class, layout

I am beginning developing android application. What I need to know is how to associated a xml layout file with a new class (not the activity). For example the class needs to have a table with an image and some texts.

thanks!

Comment: same problem... searching for an answer for 3 hours

Answer (score 4):

Got the answer try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourxmllayout, null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this like:

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.yourxmllayout, null);
```

If you are in activity there is no need to use context.

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html